# Prediction on validation database

Tags: python, scikit-learn, probability, prediction, supervised-learning

How can I obtain the prediction on my validation database with proba1 and proba2 (supervised modeling) and with the others variables please.
Thanks.

I don't want to have only the proba but all the dataset enrich with the 2 proba.

```
    probas=model.predict_proba(chq_score) #prédiction sur la base à scorer (les nouvelles transactions)
print(probas)
df_resultats=pd.DataFrame(probas,columns=model.classes_)
df_resultats.to_csv('../Results/Score_base_validation_RandomF.csv',index=False,sep=';')
```

Comment: Idon't understand your question. What is your expected output and what is your actual output?

Comment: hello in my output I have proba_0 and proba_1, i want to have X1 X2 X3 ... proba_0 proba_1

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you precise how chq_score looks like and how df_resultats should look like? The best would be to edit your question accordingly. Thanks